# Recover Excel Files when failed to save to OneDrive on shutdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-recovery

#### So this happened...

1. When I shut down macOS, I have an unsaved document in Excel. I saved it to my OneDrive account, and then the system shuts down.
2. After I restarted macOS, I opened another unrelated document in Excel.
3. When I tried to find the document I saved to OneDrive, I cannot find it in OneDrive, nor is it in the usual unsaved works directory.

Is is possible to recover this file?

#### Versions

```
Microsoft Excel for Mac: 16.46 (21021202)
macOS Catalina: 10.15.7 (19H2)
```

Comment: Did you check the OneDrive web? http://onedrive.live.com/ And you can also refer to the article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/recover-files-in-office-for-mac-6c6425b1-6559-4bbf-8f80-4f038402ff02

Comment: What does your recent files say?  Does it show a file saved to onedrive at all? Did you check your local pc's onedrive folder? It could be that it saved there but the onedrive client hasn't synced to the cloud yet.

Comment: @Lee Thank you for your comment. I just checkeed and it's not in OneDrive web. And I did follow that official guide for restoring the file. Unfortuantely, none of the methods mentioned on that page worked.

Comment: @Mobus Thanks. The file is not in the recent files list. It does show other Excel documents I've saved to OneDrive, but it does not show the file that I lost. As for OneDrive folders, I didn't save it in an independent OneDrive folder. I saved it to OneDrive through Excel. (I don't have OneDrive installed, but I am using the OneDrive feature embedded in Excel)

Answer (score 1):

Did you look here?

[image]

I normally prefer to save to a hard drive folder from excel, and then have the onedrive desktop client sync that folder.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately the "Recover Unsaved Workbooks" button does not appear for me. Maybe this answer can help someone else in the future.

Comment: Perhaps too little to late, but have you tried to open the "Microsoft Upload Center"?